# Chrome Extension - IP and Port Valid Check

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension and I want to provide input for an IP and check the IP for a specific Port to make sure it's open/closed (My Raspberry Pi). How would one go about making the request to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to as an Extention. [image: Error]